# Average of nth element of each list in a dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, dictionary

```
D_values = {}
Average = [ ]
for path in glob("F:\Thermal Motion\*.txt"):
    t, x, y = np.loadtxt(path, unpack=True)
    D_values[path] = [((x[i]/.115 - x[0]/.115)**2 + (y[i]/.155 - y[0]/.155)**2)**0.5
                      for i in range(len(x))]
    print D_values[path]
```

When I print `D_values` it gives a bunch of lists. What I need to do is to find the average of each of the nth elements, for all the arrays. I just don't know how I'll refer to a specific list in the dictionary. Like if `D_values[path]` gives lists

```
[1,2,3,4,...]
[23,234,43,...]
[5,6,7,...]
```

I want to make an array where `Average[(1,23,5,...) (2,234,7,...)...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has basically been done for you with `np.mean`.  But you want to make your data into an array first, instead of a dict.  You can do this by saying:

```
D_values = []  # an empty list, not dict
Average = []
for path in glob("F:\Thermal Motion\*.txt"):
    t, x, y = np.loadtxt(path, unpack=True)
    #append to list instead of dict:
    D_values.append([((x[i]/.115 - x[0]/.115)**2 + (y[i]/.155 - y[0]/.155)**2)**0.5
                      for i in range(len(x))])
print D_values
```

Then you have `D_values` is a list of lists.  Now you can use `np.mean` on it:

```
np.mean(D_values, axis=0)
```

Where the `axis=0` argument tell the function to average along the first axis (columns).

So, if `D_values` is `[[1,2,3], [23,234,43], [5,6,7]]`, then you'll get your mean as: `[  9.66666667,  80.66666667,  17.66666667]`

Protip: You don't have to build your D_values with a list comprehension, since `t`, `x`, and `y` are arrays. You can do:

```
D_values = []  # an empty list, not dict
Average = []
for path in glob("F:\Thermal Motion\*.txt"):
    t, x, y = np.loadtxt(path, unpack=True)
    #append to list instead of dict:
    D_values.append((((x - x[0])/.115)**2 + ((y - y[0])/.155)**2)**0.5)
print D_values
```